# Angularjs $http post error in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, httpservice

Here is my controller. When I want to post some data to backend, I get error.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($http, $scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://cms.focusweb.ir/Json/get_article',
      data: { id: 25 },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .success(function(response) {
      // handle success things
      console.log(response);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // handle error things
  })
})
```

The **error** I get :

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://cms.focusweb.ir/Json/get_article
No more request expected
at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1207)
at sendReq (ionic.bundle.js:19160)
at status.$get.serverRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18872)
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:23394)
at ionic.bundle.js:23410
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24673)
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24484)
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24778)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:19191)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19363)
```

**NOTE:** I have already used this controller code in other project, but it works fine.

Comment: 'Unexpected request' - it looks like you suddenly included ngMock module (or other module for testing)

Comment: @STEVER yes, exactly. In `app.js` I included `ngMockE2E`. That's why it works in other porjects. What should I do?

Comment: @STEVER I cleaned `ngMockE2E` and testing part and now it works perfect. If you post the answer, I would accept it as an accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: welcome :) posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with "**ngMockE2E**" AngularJS module that should be used only for tests and not included like dependency for you project.

So solution: just remove this dependancy.

Answer (score -1):

You have to describe $httpbackend.whenPOST in your app.js

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST('http://cms.focusweb.ir/Json/get_article')`enter code here`
    .respond();
```